# Background-image cover doesn't work on smaller screens

Tags: css, background-image, cover

I'd like to use an image as a background for my header.
Here's what it looks like now:

[image: A rectangular photo with a curved bottom edge and a red curved line just below it.]

Now here's my mobile version:
[image: A taller rectangular photo with a straight bottom edge. There is white space between the photo and the curved red line.]

As you can see, there's a blank space that I don't want here. I've tried using vh/vw, setting the body height at 100%, but it doesn't work.

```css
.home .part1-img-container {
  min-height: 650px;
  background-color: grey;
  background: url(assets/img/brooklyn.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  /*padding-top: 70px;*/
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 10%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 10%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-position-y: -187px;
}
```

```html
<div class="part1 col-md-12 col-lg-12 p-0">
  <div class="part1-img-container">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried to do this without setting a `min-height`

Comment: The problem is clearly the min-height, I was added an answer but I misunderstood the question, so @Toxide82 seems to be right.

Comment: Still doesn't work :/ I think the min-height sets the minimum height for the div, not for the background-image unfortunately

Comment: I don't have a media query on that, I think I found a fix by manually setting the width and height of the background image, I'll update my original post !

Comment: Why are you using: background-position-y: -187px; ?

Comment: With the actual picture I'm using ( just can't show it ), the interesting part of the image is hidden by the navbar

Comment: I have made a fiddle out of the code you have presented. Without background-position-y: -187px; it is working fine in mobile and desktop both. http://jsfiddle.net/51f7w6q0/13/